# Android Maps Intent - Extra Parameters

Tags: android, google-maps, android-intent, google-maps-markers

Right now, I'm launching the Google Maps application with the following call:

```
String geoAddress = "maps.google.com/maps?q=";
geoAddress += LatLong[0] + "," + LatLong[1];    
Intent i = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse(geoAddress));
startActivity(i);
```

Which will open and place a marker at the specified position on the map. I have two questions:

**1)** How can I place multiple markers of which I have the Longitude/Latitude?

**2)** How can I start the Maps application to other modes (terrain/satellite/etc.)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. you can add multiple links on the map by using overlays,and u can see the GoogleMapview example in http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html.
   here you can understand use of overlays.

Read the following links and download the code the link(For Further reference)

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons

https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-mapviewballoons#readme

2.To change the views use following functions,
    mapView.setSatellite(true);
   mapView.setStreetView(true);
For further reference
http://mobiforge.com/developing/story/using-google-maps-android

Comment: http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html.  this is the link discard here in the link

Comment: Thanks I'm going to explore this a bit.

Comment: MapView contains the options `setSatellite()` and `setStreetView()` but nothing for **terrain** mode (the mode important).

Comment: Yeah, but we worked on only 3 modes, we didnt work on terrain view

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying. There is a terrain option in Google Maps, and I want to access it. How do I do that?

Comment: @RedLeader let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/1700/discussion-between-titus-and-redleader)

Comment: Overall I guess Google just didn't enable terrain view. Which is unfortunate. Otherwise, these examples worked fine, thank you!